# How to re-enable AMD Turbo Core

Tags: windows-8, cpu, sony-vaio, turbo-boost

I have Sony Vaio Fit 15e (Canadian model around May 2013) with AMD A10-5745M, 2.10 GHz quad core. Because of AMD Turbo Core, the CPU runs upto 2.70 GHz when plugged in, but the problem is that if I sleep and wake up, Turbo Core disables itself completely so the CPU speed becomes 2.10 GHz max. TO tweak the setting, I downloaded AMD Overdrive. However, I accidentally disabled Turbo Core by changing CPU Core 0 Multiplier, and I can't enable Turbo Core because Turbo Core control was greyed out. How do I re-enable Turbo Core again?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled Overdrive, restarted, and reinstalled Overdrive. Turbo Core worked again.

However, the problem of Turbo Core being disabled after waking up from sleeping is still there, and the only workaround is to hibernate.